# How to redirect the user to home page in routes in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I need to redirect the user to the home page if he goes to any page that is not found i.e.,404 error

I saw this in [Laravel Error Handling](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/errors#handling-errors)

But is it possible to do that in routes ?

```
Route::get('/', 'MainController@MainPage');
```

above given is my route for home

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to do it in your routes then you should have this in the top of your routes

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return Redirect::to('/');
});
```